# Hubs compatible with 7 speed cassette

Tags: hub

I have one Gt aggressor 2.0 2014 and want to make some upgrade. So someone told me to buy a new hub to use with a 9 speed cassette. I want to buy the hub but later the 9v cassette, so has any hub can use 7 speed cassette?

Comment: I removed the request for shopping advice, because it is off-topic here - such advice becomes obsolete very quickly.

Answer (score 7):

The GT Aggressor 2.0 2014 ships with a rear wheel which uses a freewheel, so if you want to go 9 speed, you need a rear wheel which has a Shimano-compatible cassette freehub as well as a 9 speed rear shifter which is Shimano compatible (and obviously a 9 speed cassette).

Buying a new rear wheel will be likely cheaper and more reliable than having the existing rear wheel rebuilt with a freehub. A 9 speed cassette freehub can use a 7 speed cassette with a spacer.

However, I'd recommend against the whole idea -- by the time you've done this, you've spent likely half the cost of a cheap bike like the Aggressor 2.0 and with the low spec of the rest of the bike, you're not really going to see performance gains (especially for the amount of money you're spending). If you want 9 speed, sell the bike you have and buy something is 9 speed already.